# Display hex values on LCD using 8051 MCU

Tags: c, embedded, 8051

I have calculated `TH1=0xA5,TL1=0xFE` by ultrasonic sensor on. I want to display it on a LCD (16*2) like `A5FE` using an 8051 MCU. My problem is that I'm using an integer value for displaying on the LCD.

Now I want to create a variable `a` which will contain the value `0xA5FE`, that is `a=0xA5FE`. How can I combine the value of TH1 and TL1?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming TH1, TL1 are `uint8_t`:

```
uint16_t a = ((uint16_t)TH1 << 8) | TL1;
```